# estout loop with different regressions results

Tags: stata

I want to easily select a regressor among a list of regressor that negatively affects the dependent variable and minimizes the BIC criterion within a loop. To do so, I would like to present all the coefficient estimates in an Excel table (or a .dta file), providing coefficient estimates, p-value, BIC, R-squared, number of clusters, and observations. I provide here an example, but the data I want to extract are not correctly displayed. How can I have all the estimates on the same line and not in a diagonal as it is currently displayed?

```
sysuse auto, clear
         
         
global min "1800 2000 2500 3000"
global max "3500 4000 4500 5000"
        
foreach min of global min{
foreach max of global max{
gen weight_`min'_`max' = weight>=`min' & weight<=`max'
}
}
        
        
        
foreach min of global min{
foreach max of global max{
reg price weight_`min'_`max', cluster(foreign)
estimates store weight_`min'_`max'
}
}
        
estout weight* using "results_weight.xls",  cells(b(star fmt(%9.3f)) p(par fmt(%9.3f))) starlevels(* 0.1 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) varwidth(18) modelwidth(16) stats(r2 N bic)  keep(weight*) replace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example. Without any comments as to the desirability of this procedure, or use of global macros (experienced Stata programmers usually prefer local macros):

I haven't used `estout` in a few years, so here is an alternative solution where you grab the estimates yourself (see `help return` and `help ereturn`; try `ereturn list` and `return list` after estimation commands to see what is posted for you to access like this) and put them into a matrix (`help matrix`), creating your own table directly. You can then export that matrix into a .dta or excel or whatever your heart desires (`help svmat`; `help putexcel`).

```
sysuse auto, clear
         
         
global min "1800 2000 2500 3000"
global max "3500 4000 4500 5000"
        
foreach min of global min{
foreach max of global max{
gen weight_`min'_`max' = weight>=`min' & weight<=`max'
}
}
        
        
local counter = 1      // keep track of which loop iteration is running  
foreach min of global min{
foreach max of global max{

reg price weight_`min'_`max', cluster(foreign)
    * store the estimates you want (apart from BIC) in a matrix (really a row-vector) we call "row"
    mat row = `min', `max', r(table)[1,1], r(table)[4,1], `e(r2)', `e(N_clust)', `e(N)'

*estimate the BIC
estat ic
    * add the BIC to the row vector we created
    mat row = row, r(S)[1,6]

* if it's the first iteration, define a new matrix we call "table", which equals the row vector. if it's not the first iteration, append the the row vector to the existing table matrix
if `counter' == 1 mat table = row
else mat table = table \ row

local ++counter     // increment the counter to keep track of which loop iteration we're on
}
}

* label the columns of the matrix
matrix colnames table = min max b p r2 N_clust N BIC

* one way of exporting the matrix into data
clear
svmat table, names(col)
```